# Cleanup objects throwing error in constructor

Tags: javascript, exception, memory-leaks, error-handling, constructor

Simplified example..

Javascript object constructor

```
var Foo = function() {
    someEventEmitter.on("event", this.someHandler);
    throw new Error("Unexpected error happening in a constructor");
}
// ...

var myObject;
try {
    myObject = new Foo();
} catch(e) {

}
```

Some real world case happens in a similar way to the example above. An object is attempted constructed, but the constructor (or possibly a parent constructor) throw an error. Could be programmed operational throw, or some bug like a reference error.

Before the exception is thrown, a listener or other data is set on/by the constructor. How can this be handled to avoid memory leak and events being emitted on the failed objects? Clean up the garbage, remove added listeners and such.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle it in the constructor, either

1. Ideally by doing everything that can throw *before* the things that you may need to clean up, which is nice and simple.
2. If you can't do that, then you'll need to have a `try...catch` around your code to clean up.

Example of #2:

```
var Foo = function() {
    var emitterHooked = false;
    try {
        someEventEmitter.on("event", this.someHandler);
        emitterHooked = true;
        throw new Error("Unexpected error happening in a constructor");
    } catch (e) {
        if (emitterHooked) {
            try { 
                someEventEmitter.off("event", this.someHandler);
            } catch (e2) { }
        }
        throw e;
    }
};
```

Of course, with many event mechanisms, you don't really need the `emitterHooked` variable as removing one that has never been added is a no-op, but that was to emphasize the kinds of things you need to deal with when following that approach.

As you can see, that's really ugly, hence #1 above. :-)

Comment: #1 helps a lot, but does not ensure handling any unforseen error (not that you always need to). #2 would catch everything (except for async of course), the problem is that it requires a try-catch in every constructor. For a set of classes being used as part of an architecture, it would be nice to be able to catch them at usage point instead of one catch per class/object.